# How to measure power consumption of Jetson TX1?

Tags: nvidia, measurement, consumption

I'm trying to measure power consumption of NVIDIA's Jetson TX1 system.

I tried the following command:

```
$ watch cat /sys/devices/platform/7000c400.i2c/i2c-1/1-0040/iio_device/in_power0_input
```

I guess `0` in `in_power0_input` means to measure the whole system's power consumption.

But I don't know what the result of the command means. Is this in watts? (maybe not because it's huge number) or any other unit?

[image: in_power0_input command result]

- Or if there is any other way to measure power consumption of the board, can anyone let me know?